# Google Recaptcha V3 returning low score for legitimate users

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I have integrated google recaptcha v3 with login page. Based on the score returned by recaptcha v3 I am blocking the users from login. It works fine for most of the users but there are a set of users they are continuously getting a very low score. I don't have any access to user's system but I have the information that all the users are using the same IP address.

I am using recaoptcha enterprise site key.
Is it possible that recaptcha is providing a low score due to the Ip address? How do i unblock these users?

Comment: We are also experiencing increased number of low scores for legit users since the beginning of the month.

Comment: You can make your own safe list and add legitimate users to it, and then only use recaptcha for users who aren't on the safe list. Aside from that, I have the same questions/problems as you.